# How to see custom apps and their permissions in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I intend to access my Sharepoint site from an application using .Net.

I have created a custom app using the very hidden [appregnew.aspx page](https://piyushksingh.com/2018/12/26/register-app-in-sharepoint/) (why isn't it available in any menu?).

[image]

Unfortunately, its permission needs to be changed so I found another hidden page: [appinv.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

[image]

As a tenant admin, I can't give full access to the app and I also can't even see what permissions my app has. I changed the permission to *full access* to sitecollection:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />  
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Unfortunately, I get a 403 error so I need to change again.

How can I see and change the permissions? Why can't I see the app in the applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the apps in following url

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/AppPrincipals.aspx

when you want to change the app. You can only delete it or look up the client id in appinv.aspx.